# Generate equirectangle images from 6 fisheyes images

Tags: image, opencv, projection, panoramas

Generate equirectangle images from 6 fisheyes images
Hello,

I am new to this area and your input would be highly appreciated. I have fisheye images which are supposed to cover the whole 360 degree horizontal and 180 degree vertical area. I want to *create* equirectangle image which I will later project into sphere. Can somebody lead me into the steps or lead me to some tutorials or terms to google ?

I want to implement and code the functions myself. So I am thinking along these lines:

1- project fisheye images into some planes
2- sticth the projected images in some way
3- change the stiched image into equirectangular image

Is this the right direction ? if yes, what type of projection should i project my fisheyes images to ? Is there any specific way to stitch the images to create the equirectangle image ?

Any input, tutorials, and direction would be highly appreciated,

Thank you

p.s.

I saw someone`s project.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9H-Mgy5ePCaY0JyR0dnVDYyMEU/edit?usp=sharing
This is the picture taken with smartphone camera and fish-eye lens

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9H-Mgy5ePCaQ1NrbWhfMzZVUjg/edit?usp=sharing 
He said this is the picture using equirectangle